# OpenLayers add text clickable in the middle of linestring (OpenLayers version"^6.13.0")

Tags: angular, typescript, text, click, openlayers-6

i would like to know if it is possible to show text in Linestring setStyle only one time in the middle of it.

Basically i've a linestring with a color and display a text in it. But in the map it appears too many times and i want to display it only one time for each line, in the middle. I want also that the text is clickable and connect to it an action that i already have. This is the code below:

```
const feature = new Feature({
          geometry: lineString,
          name: 'Line'
        });
          feature.setStyle(new Style({
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: '#EE360F',
              width: 5
            }),
          text: new Text({
            text: "test",
            font: '6px "Roboto", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            fill: new Fill({ color: 'black' }),
            stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'black', width: 1 })
          })
        }),
      );
```

If it can help, i've also a button connected to a function that shows me a view in the middle of the linestring. Code below:

```
 moveMapView(){
        const view = new View({
          center: fromLonLat([(initialLongitude + endLongitude)/2, (initialLatitude + endLatitude)/2]),
          zoom: 17,
        });
        this.map?.setView(view);
      }
```

Thanks in advice

Expecting to have a text in the middle of the lineString clickable

Comment: Your style should show the text only once per line at the midpoint of the line (as long as you are not using vector tiles where the line may be divided between tiles) e..g. draw a line with https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-q374gk?file=/main.js  Do you want to be able to click only on the text and not on the stroke?  Also what do you mean by `middle of the lineString` - your view `center` is not the midpoint of the line (or even on the line) unless you have a straight line.

Comment: yes, you're right. The problem is that i have too many lines and too many text appears. So i thought to only show text when hoover on that specific line, the text must be clickable so i can connect that to an action.. the view is aproximately the center and not pointing the exact center cause it's not a straight line but that was the only way, considering my experience and my knowledge, to show the line to the viewers.

Comment: You can use a pointermove Select interaction to style the line with text when you hover over it, and use a style without text at other times.  When the text appears the line will also be detected when you click on it.  https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-labels-forked-p7vq1x?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I'll be glad to set your answer the solution for my problem, thanks a lot you saved me!